# How to get into CoreDNS pod kuberrnetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, coredns

I have a running k8s cluster with two replicas of CoreDNS. But when i try enter the bash prompt of the POD it's throwing me below error

```
# kubectl exec -it coredns-5644d7b6d9-285bj -n kube-system sh
error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "94f45da89fa5493a8283888464623788ef5e832dc31e0d89e427e71d86391fd6": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

But i am able to login to other pods without any issues. I tried with nsenter with kernel process ID it works but it only works for network related openrations like,

```
# nsenter -t 24931 -n ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth0@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 7a:70:99:aa:53:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.0.2/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7870:99ff:feaa:536c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How to enter into this pod using kubectl and get rid of that error?

Comment: why do you wanna get into CoreDNS? what is it you are trying to debug?

Comment: I am trying to check the entry in `/etc/coredns/Corefile` for one of my application service.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the sidecar pattern following the instructions here:  https://support.rancher.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041568712-How-to-troubleshoot-using-the-namespace-of-a-container#sidecar-container-0-2

In short, do this to find a node where a coredns pod is running:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get po -o wide | grep coredns
```

ssh to one of those nodes, then:

```
docker ps -a | grep coredns
```

Copy the Container ID to clipboard and run:

```
ID=<paste ID here>
docker run -it --net=container:$ID --pid=container:$ID --volumes-from=$ID alpine sh
```

You will now be inside the "sidecar" container and can poke around.  I.e.

```
cat /etc/coredns/Corefile
```

Comment: My K8s is using containerd and `docker` does not show any containers, but `crictl` does. However, `crictl` does not understand all of those command line parameters. Is there a wariant of this fpr `crictl`?

Answer (score 13):

There is a way of getting access to the filesystem of the `coredns` pod in Kubernetes.

[Debugging with ephemeral containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container) is the way to go as the image does not contain any shell.

```bash
$ kubectl debug -it coredns-6d4b75cb6d-77d86 --image=busybox:1.28 --target=coredns
```

I changed to `kube-system` namespace using

```bash
$ kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=kube-system
```

But the `-n` option can also be used in the command.

Attaching a ephemeral container with `--target` option enables [process namespace sharing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/)

After getting access to the terminal, you can view processes with:

```bash
$ ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:08 /coredns -conf /etc/coredns/Corefile
  210 root      0:00 sh
  266 root      0:00 ps aux
```

The `PID` of the coredns process is `1` and the **container filesystems are visible to other containers in the pod through the `/proc/$pid/root` link. This makes debugging easier, but it also means that filesystem secrets are protected only by filesystem permissions.** ([docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/#understanding-process-namespace-sharing))

Finally, the config file can be viewed at

```bash
$ cat /proc/1/root/etc/coredns/Corefile
.:53 {
    errors
    health {
       lameduck 5s
    }
    ready
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
       pods insecure
       fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
       ttl 30
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
       max_concurrent 1000
    }
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to check the Corefile then you can run below

```
kubectl get cm coredns -n kube-system -o yaml
```

Comment: But this will be the intial configuration right? Once the PODs are added, coredns will start adding the domains of each pods into dns table right? How can i check that?

Comment: That will not be there in core dns pod. You need to check in etc/resolve.conf file inside the application pod. BTW each pod don't have their own domain

Comment: Ok, so when i do nslookup (from busybox for suppose) from some it reaches the DNS ip and resolves it right? Where does it tries to lookup and resolve it?

Comment: /etc/resolve.conf will have core dns pod ip as nameserver