# Connect to CoreDNS pod in microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, coredns

For some troubleshooting, I want to connect to my coredns pod. Is this possible?

```
$ microk8s kubectl get pod --namespace kube-system
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hostpath-provisioner-5c65fbdb4f-w6fmn     1/1     Running   1          7d22h
coredns-7f9c69c78c-mcdl5                  1/1     Running   1          7d23h
calico-kube-controllers-f7868dd95-hbmjt   1/1     Running   1          7d23h
calico-node-rtprh                         1/1     Running   1          7d23h
```

When I try, I get the following error msg:

```
$ microk8s kubectl --namespace kube-system  exec --stdin --tty coredns-7f9c69c78c-mcdl5 -- /bin/bash
error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "f1d08ed8494894d1281cd5c43dee36119225ab1ba414def333659538e5edc561": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Comment: Coredns Pod have no shell, I think. Check this to kind-of exec with a sidecar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666170/how-to-get-into-coredns-pod-kuberrnetes

Answer (score 0):

User [AndD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11970424/andd) has good mentioned in the comment:

> Coredns Pod have no shell, I think. Check this to kind-of exec with a sidecar: [How to get into CoreDNS pod kuberrnetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666170/how-to-get-into-coredns-pod-kuberrnetes)

Yes. This image has no shell. You can read more about this situation in [this thread](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/3533):

> The image does not contain a shell. Logs can be viewed with `kubectl`.

You have asked:

> I want to connect to my coredns pod, is this possible?

Theoretically yes, but you need to make a workaroud with docker. It is described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67237802/15407542):
In short, do this to find a node where a coredns pod is running:

```yaml
kubectl -n kube-system get po -o wide | grep coredns
```

ssh to one of those nodes, then:

```yaml
docker ps -a | grep coredns
```

Copy the Container ID to clipboard and run:

```yaml
ID=<paste ID here>
docker run -it --net=container:$ID --pid=container:$ID --volumes-from=$ID alpine sh
```

You will now be inside the "sidecar" container and can poke around. I.e.

```yaml
cat /etc/coredns/Corefile
```

Additionally, you can check the logs, with `kubectl`. See also [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) about DNS debugging.

Comment: I will only have time on Monday to try it out. But will I be able to do something like `ping` as if it comes from the `coredns pod`?

Comment: You have to do exactly as I described in the answer, or check the logs.

Comment: Okay I tried the way described there, but I can't ssh into one of the nodes because in microk8s everything runs on the main host. So jumped straight to step number 3 but here docker throws an error: `docker: Error response from daemon: No such container: coredns-7f9c69c78c-mcdl5.`

Comment: The answer is correct because to find the container you need to login to node, not host.

Comment: I kind of solved the issues that I tried to solve, so this is no longer necessary to do for me.